# How to detect which element of array is shown in imageView?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, random, android-image

I want to randomly set resource in imageView and after that, check which element in an array is shown. How it could be possible? I'm a beginner.

```
var three = intArrayOf(R.drawable.na3,R.drawable.na4)
    image_view.setImageResource(three[random.nextInt(three.size)])
                if (three[1]){
                //Do stuff
                }
```

In "three[1]" I'm getting error:

> Type mismatch. 
>   Required:
>   Boolean
>   Found:
>   Int

Comment: Where do you need to check the element? Right after setting it there? If so, then simply use a separate variable for the random `int`, and use it to set the image, and to do the comparison; e.g., `val idx = random.nextInt(three.size)`, `image_view.setImageResource(three[idx])`, `if (idx == 1) ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
 val arrayList = listOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background1,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background2,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background3)
    val randomNumber = Random().nextInt(arrayList.size)

    imageView.setImageResource(arrayList[randomNumber])
    when (randomNumber){
        0-> println("Index is 0")
        1-> println("Index is 1")
        2-> println("Index is 2")
        else->
            println("Error")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save randomIndex first then use this randomIndex's item as following code do-

```
  val randomIndex=Random.nextInt(0, three.size)
    imageView.setImageResource(three[randomIndex])
    /* x is your compare int (ImageResource id) */
    if(three[randomIndex]==x){
        /*Do your stuff here */
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for asnwer but "nextInt" shows me unresolved reference, where problem could be?

Comment: You need to use kotlin rendom function 
import kotlin.random.Random

Answer (score 0):

You have error because you are providing int value to 'if'.You should provide boolean only.

Try

```
var three = intArrayOf(R.drawable.na3,R.drawable.na4)
    image_view.setImageResource(three[random.nextInt(three.size)])
                if (three.indexOf(getDrawableId(image_view))==1){
                //Do stuff
            }
```

2nd option
try switch

Comment: Thanks for answer but "getDrawableId" shows me unresolved reference. How to solve this?